# Chamar servlet em um popup

Tags: javascript, java

Bom dia, galera...

Como posso executar um servlet abrindo em um popup e passando 1 parametro ?
Meu código está assim :
- Na pagina que chama

```
<form name="frmcadentidade" method="get" action="DetalheEntidade">
   <input type='submit' id='btncnes' onclick='abrirConsulta()' 
   value='CONSULTAR'></input>
</form>

function abrirConsulta(){
window.open ('servlets/DetalheEntidade.java', 'pagina', 
"width=250 height=250 left=400 top=250");
}
```

No caso, o parametro que quero passar é outro value para esse button.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode resolver este problema utilizando requisições `ajax`, e utilizar a biblioteca javascript `jQuery`.

Vou simular seu `servelet` no meu exemplo:

```js
//este é um exemplo de ajax sendo chamado ao clickar em um botao qualquer do seu html.

//ele pega o id do botao, e no click desse botao ele começa a função ajax
$('#btncnes').click(function(){ 
  var valorInput = $("#value").val();  
  alert("funcionou, texto do input: "+valorInput);  
  $.ajax({ 
    //aqui a url do seu servelet, no caso eu "usei um servelet publico"
    url: 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cdYItaXpvm?indent=2', 
    //o tipo do metodo GET,POST, PUT, DELETE
    type: 'GET', 
    //os dados que eu vou enviar é mais usado quando voce vai inserir algo ou alterar
    data: {valorInput: valorInput},
    //caso de certo o que fazer:
    success: function(data) { 
      console.log('retorno do servelet');
      console.log(data);
    } 
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="frmcadentidade" action="DetalheEntidade">
   <input type='text' value="seu texto" id='value' />
   <button type='button' id='btncnes' onclick='podechamarAfuncaoAjaxPorAquiTb()'>CONSULTAR</button>
</form>
```

Comentei como funciona essa requisição, e desta maneira você consegue chamar um servlet de qualquer lugar que tenha um ID :D

Comment: Mas onde se encaixa a configuração da popup ?